# CSS Button Element Class "Inheritance"

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm new to this, but none of the other q/a's on the topic seem to help me, so I will ask.

Here is some code:

```
<style>
button.accordion {
background-color: #eee
//a list of other details
}

other stuff that manipulates button.accordion
</style>
```

Now, I want to do something like this:

```
<button class="accordion">Personnel</button>
<div class="panel">
<p>contents of personnel here</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Necessary Expenditures</button>
<div class="panel">
<p>contents of expenditures here</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Personnel</button>
<div class="panel">
<p>contents of personnel here</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Necessary Expenditures</button>
<div class="panel">
 <p>contents of expenditures here</p>
</div>
```

And I want them all to be class="accordion" so that they function the same way, but I want to override background-color so that a couple of them have a different color.

I have tried adding a class like so:

```
<style>
.green {
background-color: #669900;
}
</style>
```

and then:

```
<button class="accordion green">Personnel</button>
<div class="panel">
<p>contents of personnel here</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Necessary Expenditures</button>
<div class="panel">
 <p>contents of expenditures here</p>
</div>
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Anyway I can do this?

I am using javascript so that the buttons act as collapsible sections to my page.

Comment: The reason is that you are using `button` and `.accordion` at the top so it has a lot of specificity. While the one you want to make green just has `.green`. This one isn't as specific and so it's overshadowed by your more specific default. You can combine classes so that the green one has a higher level of specificity. Like this: `button.accordion.green { }`

Comment: and then when I call it, how do i complete this
    <button class=" ">

Comment: Just like you did: `<button class="accordion green">Personnel</button>`

Comment: this doesn't seem to work

Comment: it does work, i am sorry, i had dropped a 9 in my hex at some point

Answer (score 2):

Use selectors `button.accordion`, `button.green`. Comment at `css` is `/**/`, not `//`. `#66900` is not a valid hex color. Include missing `9` at `button.green` `background-color` value.

```css
button.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  /* css comment */
  /* a list of other details */

}
button.green {
  background-color: #669900; 
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion green">Personnel</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>contents of personnel here</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Necessary Expenditures</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>contents of expenditures here</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Personnel</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>contents of personnel here</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Necessary Expenditures</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>contents of expenditures here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: how do i then call the class when doing <button class="accordion...">

Comment: `#66900;` is also not a valid hex color.

Comment: sorry yes, i missed a 9

Comment: What do you mean by "call the class"? At `javascript`?

Answer (score 1):

`button.accordion` is a more specific style than just `.accordion` or `.green` that is why it is given priority. Instead of applying styles to `button.accordion` apply style to `.accordion` and be more specific on individual styles like `button.green`.

```
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
}
button.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

or you can simply use ID for specific buttons.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
button.accordion {
/*background-color: #eee;*/
}
.green {
 background-color: green;
}
.red {
 background-color: red;
}
.blue {
 background-color: blue;
}
.default {
 background-color: #EEE;
}
</style>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<button class="accordion green">Personnel</button>
<div class="panel">
<p>contents of personnel here</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion red">Necessary Expenditures</button>
<div class="panel">
<p>contents of expenditures here</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion blue">Personnel</button>
<div class="panel">
<p>contents of personnel here</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion default">Necessary Expenditures</button>
<div class="panel">
 <p>contents of expenditures here</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Why are you specifying a default background color? Just create a class called "default" and set the background to `#EEE` on the buttons that need to be that color.